# passing a pointer to a long by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, declaration

I have been trying to find an answer and get this to work for a while now and so I figured I'd check here. I am trying to pass a pointer to a long by reference. The syntax I'm using is:

```
int Hex2Loong(long*& bytebuff, int& len, const std::string Hexbuff);
```

The error shows up whenever I try to declare the function. The definition itself surprisingly
seems to have no issues. I'm using the same exact syntax with a `int*&` in my `Hex2Int` fcn
and there are no problems there. Any ideas what I'm messing up?

The error I'm getting is:
    error:in passing argument 1 of Hex2Loong(long int*&,int &,const std::string);

On a related note if I have a `unsigned long *` I take it there is no way to cast that so I
can pass it into the `Hex2Loong` function right? I will have to create temporary `long *`
vars cast into them and pass those?

Ty for any answers,
    Drf

Edit:
Hmm ok so to answer some of the comments.
I pass a reference since the function converts a possibly very long hexadecimal string
to an array of longs. (i.e. think a number on the order of 2^1000 written as a hex string)
and I need to pass the number back as an array of longs (I will probably rewrite it for
unsigned longs since the no casting makes it cumbersome).

The HexString is declared as const since it's supposed to be (it should not be modified only read).

And finally you were quite right the error had nothing to do with the declaration but 
rather with the usage. The fact that I was trying to pass `(long *) num1` where num1
was `unsigned long *` was messing everything up. I still don't get why the error showed
up in the header file though instead of just the place where I was actually calling
the function with the wrong parameters.

Edit2: Ooh I just realized what you meant by passing `const std::string&`. And of course
you're exactly right. I will change that aswell. It's what I get for writing in java
too much. I didn't realize the string would actually get copied.

Comment: Can you show us where you call it?

Comment: can you include how the function is called? based on your error, the declaration is fine, but the usage is incorrect

Comment: 1) Why do you pass `Hexbuff` by value instead of by reference ? 2) As if you use STL (std::string at least) maybe it would be better to fill `std::vector< long >` (by passing it by ref. too)

Comment: You're passing a valid *reference* to a `long *` for the call, correct? From what I see the only 'unusual' thing in this decl is the constant *copy* of whatever `Hexbuff` is. Not sure if you intended to use `const std::string&` ?

Comment: AFAIK four most popular compilers (MSVC, ICC, GCC, CLang) on popular platforms (PC and MAC) consider `long` the same length as `int` - 4 bytes. If you want to have 8 bytes integer type, you should use `long long` or `int64_t`

Comment: WhozCraig could you perchance write what you wrote in the comment as a post? Since pretty much your comment was the right answer. Also at borisbn my gcc definitely think long and int are different long being 8 bytes and int 4.

Comment: @Drf I beg your pardon... gcc and CLang treats `long` as 4 bytes in 32-bit platforms and 8 bytes at 64.

Comment: @borisbn Ahh yeah that might be it. I'm running on a 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call that function fine with something like:

```
long lvar;
long *plvar = &lvar;
int rc = Hex2Loong (plvar, some_int, some_string);
```

What you *can't* do is pass the address of the long, since you need a real reference. In other words, don't try:

```
long lvar;
int rc = Hex2Loong (&lvar, some_int, some_string);
```

See the following sample code:

```
void Fn (long * &p1) {}

int main (void) {
    long lvar;
    long *plvar = &lvar;
    Fn (plvar);
    //Fn (&lvar);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles okay but complains when you uncomment the `&lvar` line.

---

In terms of your second question, no, you need an actual variable that can be passed as a reference, simply because the function may attempt to change it. So you'll need to make a temporary copy somewhere.

However, keep in mind that, unless you actually need to *change* the value of the variable you're passing in (so that such a change is reflected in the calling code), there's no need to pass a reference. You can just pass it by value and use the value within the function.

If you do that (ie, if you don't need to change it), you can then use temporaries like `&lvar` or `(long*)(unsigned_long_ptr_variable)` in the function call.

Comment: +1, I suspect the latter is the case as well. Perhaps we'll see.